# Orthonormal total set in Hilbert spaces under isomorphism.

Tags: functional-analysis

An Isomorphism of an Hilbert space $H$ onto a Hilbert space $\tilde{H}$ over the same field is a bijective linear operator $T\colon H\to\tilde{H}$ such that for all $x,y\in H$ $$\langle Tx, Ty\rangle_{\tilde{H}}=\langle x ,y\rangle_H. \tag1$$

Let $M$ be a total orthonormal set in $H$ I must prove that $T(M)$ is an total orthonormal set in $\tilde{H}$.It is clear from $(1)$ that orthonormal elements in $H$ have orthonormal images under $T$ and then the set $T(M)$ is orthonormal. It remains to prove that $T(M)$ is total. I reasoned as follows:
suppose by absurd that $T(M)$ is not total in $\tilde{H}$, then exists $\tilde{y}\in \tilde{H}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $\tilde{y}\perp T(M)$ that is $$\langle\tilde{y},y\rangle=0\quad \forall y\in T(M).$$ Since $T$ is bijective exists a unique $x_1\in H$ and a unique $x_2\in M$ such that $Tx_1=\tilde{y}$ and $Tx_2=y$...

Using the John Doe's hints we obtain: for all $y\in T(M)$ exists a unique $x_2\in H$ such that $Tx_2=y$, then we have that $$\langle x_1, x_2\rangle=\langle Tx_1, Tx_2\rangle =\langle\tilde{y}, y\rangle=0.$$ From this we obtain that $x_1\perp x_2$, can I conclude that $x_1\perp M$?

Thanks!

Comment: Show that $x_1\perp M$ by the isometry-property of $T$ and $M$ is total therefore $x_1 = 0$.

Comment: @JohnDoeThanks to your suggestion I've taken a step forward, but now there's a further doubt that I put as a question in the post. Thank you.

Comment: You need to let $x_2$ vary over $M$, not just for one of its members.

Comment: If I start from the fact that $y\in T(M)$, How can I make $x_2$ vary over $M$?

Comment: Just let $x_2$ vary over $M$ and then $Tx_2$ varies over $T(M)$.  No need to go backwards.

Comment: Yes. I understand.  Thanks!